# This is a question based on Newton's laws of motion.I couldn't even get an idea about it

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics

[image]

A heavy cylindrical shaft of massM is  vertically through a distance s into the ground by the blow of a pile driver of mass m.the pile driver drops vertically through a distance h onto the head of the pile.find the average resistance of the ground

Comment: Hi Anu and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that we don't answer homework or worked example type questions. Please see [this page in the site help](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for more on what topics you can ask about here.

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

To start with ignore the resistance of the ground and look at the impact between the pile driver m and the shaft M.  Momentum is conserved.

The combined m+M now has a certain kinetic energy.

After the system has come to rest, at a distance s lower than it was on impact, it has less potential energy and no kinetic energy.

All that energy, kinetic plus potential, has done work.  It provided a force x distance pushing the pile into the ground.  You know the distance, calculate the force.

OK?